How to make all math render in a command?
Note: This question was asked this morning, but the author deleted it after I answered. I'm reposting it now to keep track of my answer.


I  want all my math to render in $\ce{...}$. So, for example, if I type $HCl$ it treats it as $\ce{HCl}$.

\ce is a command provided by the mhchem package to handle chemical equations.
Minimal working example (MWE):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

This should be rendered by the \verb|\ce| command : $ H2 $.

\end{document}


Redefining $ is really a bad idea because it's used internally by many commands, including \ce.
As alternative, you can define your own pair of delimiters, for example £...£
\char_set_catcode_active:N £
\cs_new:Npn \__jlab_ce:w #1£ { \ce{#1} }
\char_set_active_eq:NN £ \__jlab_ce:w

But not sure if it's worth it (\ce is a very short command name and will be clear to everyone, including your text editor).
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\char_set_catcode_active:N £
\cs_new:Npn \__jlab_ce:w #1£ { \ce{#1} }
\char_set_active_eq:NN £ \__jlab_ce:w
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This should be rendered by the \verb|\ce| command : £ H2 £.

\bigskip

It works inside math too: $ x + £ H2 £ $

\end{document}


